# Solving Functional Equation with an essence of Number Theory

Tags: functional-equations

> **PROBLEM STATEMENT**

Find all functions $f: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$ which satisfy:
(a) $ f $ is a surjective function;
(b) $m|n$ if and only if $f(m)|f(n)$, for any two natural numbers $m, n$.          $   \    \   \ \ $  $(1)$

> **MY PROGRESS**

I am unable to make progress in this question. All I could figure out is $f(1)=1$:

> Since $f$ is surjective, there exists $a \in \mathbb N$ such that $f(a)=1$. Now, replace $n$ by $a$ and $m$ by $1$ in $(1)$ to obtain $$f(1)|f(a) \implies f(1)|1 \implies f(1)=1 .$$This follows from the fact that $1|a$ for any choice of $a$.

Alternatively:

> Replacing $m$ by $a$ and $n$ by $1$, we obtain $$a|1 \iff f(a)|f(1) , $$ from here we conclude that $f(1)=1$.

Are both the arguments above are correct? I am confused, as I think only one is correct.

How should I progress further? Any ideas or hints will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

NOTE: I have edited this question from understanding-solution to this.

Comment: Try reframe your question to get down what exactly you don't get . Then it will be easy to answer the question

Comment: More generally, $\tau(f(n)) =\tau(n)$, which implies that $f$ permutes primes.

Comment: @lhf are you referring to sum of digits function? If so, how?

Comment: $\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function